# Fill combination column with respect ID's in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F",
        "ALL","ALL","ALL")
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Breadth","Height","Width","Width"
           ,"Length","Height_Breadth","Width")
Combination <- NA
df1 <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,Combination)
```

I am trying to fill the combination column for values "ALL" with respective ID's based on the measurement column.

```
If ID -> ALL and Measurement is Length then Combination is A,B
If ID -> ALL and Measurement is Height_Breadth then Combination is D,C
```

**My desired output is**

```
   ID    Measurement Combination
    A         Length        <NA>
    B         Length        <NA>
    C        Breadth        <NA>
    D         Height        <NA>
    E          Width        <NA>
    F          Width        <NA>
  ALL         Length         A,B
  ALL Height_Breadth         D,C
  ALL          Width         E,F
```

I am getting an error when I am trying to do this

```
if(df1$ID = 'ALL' & df1$Measurement = 'Length')
{
  df1$Combination <- paste(df1$ID, collapse=",")
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(ID != "ALL") %>% 
   group_by(Measurement = replace(Measurement, 
                Measurement %in% c("Breadth", "Height"), "Height_Breadth")) %>%
   summarise(Combination = toString(ID), ID = "ALL") %>%
   bind_rows(filter(df1, ID != "ALL"), .) 
#    ID    Measurement Combination
#1   A         Length        <NA>
#2   B         Length        <NA>
#3   C        Breadth        <NA>
#4   D         Height        <NA>
#5   E          Width        <NA>
#6   F          Width        <NA>
#7 ALL Height_Breadth        C, D
#8 ALL         Length        A, B
#9 ALL          Width        E, F
```

---

Or using `base R`, we change the `levels` of the 'Measurement' that are 'Breadth' 'Height' to 'Height_Breadth', `aggregate` the 'ID' by 'Measurement' to `paste` them together, create an 'ID' column and `merge` with the original dataset

```
levels(df1[,2])[levels(df1[,2])  %in% c("Breadth", "Height")]  <- "Height_Breadth"
d2 <- transform(aggregate(cbind(Combination = ID)~Measurement, df1, 
         subset = ID != "ALL", FUN = toString), ID = "ALL")
transform(merge(df1, d2, all.x=TRUE, by = c("ID", "Measurement")), 
                 Combination = Combination.y)[-(3:4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome solution. I had one question. Can we generalize your line1 of the base R solution? I have a bigger dataset with many "Measurement_Measurement" values. Can the code just pick the names of the measurements alone such as Height & Breadth instead of "Height_Breadth" to output C&D in the combination column?

Comment: @Sharath My first thought was a second dataset with key/value columns.  Create that smaller dataset and join with the original one based on key column

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
       # create a new group variable which transforms the Measurement, i.e, combine Breadth and Height
       group_by(Group = ifelse(Measurement %in% c("Breadth", "Height"), "Height_Breadth", Measurement)) %>% 

       # For each group paste non ALL IDs and assign it rows where ID is all
       mutate(Combination = ifelse(ID == "ALL", toString(ID[ID != "ALL"]), NA)) %>% 

       # drop Group column
       ungroup() %>% select(-Group)


# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     ID    Measurement Combination
#  <chr>          <chr>       <chr>
#1     A         Length        <NA>
#2     B         Length        <NA>
#3     C        Breadth        <NA>
#4     D         Height        <NA>
#5     E          Width        <NA>
#6     F          Width        <NA>
#7   ALL         Length        A, B
#8   ALL Height_Breadth        C, D
#9   ALL          Width        E, F
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom for the great solution. As I have asked below in my comments. Can we generalize your group_by in line3 of your solution? I have a bigger dataset with many "Measurement_Measurement" values. Can the code just pick the names of the measurements alone such as Height & Breadth instead of "Height_Breadth" to output C&D in the combination column?

Comment: In that case, you will need a Mapping table to do this programmatically, which, for instance, you can have one column as ID, another column as Measurement Type, the same ID correspond to types you want to combine as one, then you can join it with your data and group by the ID.